# String between two commas Java

Tags: java

How can i isolate a String existed between two commas?

i.e. Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul

I want to retrieve the name Marco. Which is the most appropriate way? Should i use regex?If yes,can anyone explain me how?

Comment: Which isolation level do you want?

Comment: Many answers already-  Just in case you want this for parsing a CSV file, use opencsv.  It can handle input with double quotes  ( like angelo, "marco,some", nick ...)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use `String.split(",")`

like so:

```
String str = "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul";
String[] myStrings = str.split(",");
String marco = myStrings[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String s = "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul";
String array[] = s.split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("element "+i+" "+array[i]);
}
```

Comment: without using for loop or something how I specify the location of particular name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split e.g.

```
String[] names = "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul".split(",");
// or
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul".split(","));
// or
for(String name: "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul".split(","))
    System.out.println(name);
```

Answer (score 1):

split string using comma separator.

```
 **try it**

   String str = "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul";

    String lines[]= str.split(",");
    String name = lines[1];
```

Comment: same as old answer

Answer (score 1):

Well lets not make it complicated and use `split()` and `Arrays.asList()` method....

```
String str = "Angelo,Marco,Nick,Brandon,Paul";

String[] arr = str.split(",");

List<String> alist = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arr);

String marco = alist.get(alist.indexOf("Marco"));
```

Voila..... its done... !!! Marco is with u now....