# Substring of string is not working the way i want

Tags: java, substring

I have this code here:

```
String line1 = "part1, part2, part3, part4";
```

and i  want to extract part 2.
so i tried this:

```
String extractedPart = line1.substring(line1.indexOf(","), line1.indexOf(",", line1.indexOf"," +1)));

System.out.println(extractedPart);
```

But it's not printing out anything.
Can someone help me with that?

Comment: It's not valid Java: `line1.indexOf","`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String between two commas Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12121322/string-between-two-commas-java)

Comment: When correcting the `","` to `(",")` *and* taking away one closing parenthesis at the end, this prints exactly `, part2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you use split method

```
String[] split = line1.split(",");
System.out.println(split[1]);
```

**output**

```
 part2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String extractedPart = line1.substring(line1.indexOf(",") + 1, line1.indexOf(",", line1.indexOf(",") + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

[substing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) returns the string that starts with character in the index, so you'll need to add 1 in order to avoid the comma.

```
String extractedPart = line1.substring(line1.indexOf(",") + 1, line1.indexOf(",", line1.indexOf(",") +1));
```

will output

```
 part2
```

note that the space is still there. you can avoid it by [trimming](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())